# Run unix command on awk field

Tags: awk

I want to run the basename command on a certain awk field.

```
echo "1 /this/is/a/path" | awk '{print $1" "system("/usr/bin/basename " $2)}'
```

but the output always produces a 0 from the system command. How do I print the real output?

Comment: `awk -F, '{printf "%s ",$1 ; system ("/usr/bin/basename " $2)}'`

Comment: `awk '{gsub(/\/.*\//,"",$1); print}'`

Comment: The marked duplicate isn't anything remotely similar. It discusses ways of setting an `awk` variable from a parameter. This one is concerned with getting output from a shell command executed within an `awk` script

Comment: @Costas yours should be the answer!

Answer (score 5):

POSIXly:

```
$ echo "1 /this/is/a/path" | awk '
{
  cmd = "/usr/bin/basename -- " $2;
  cmd | getline out; 
  print $1, out;
  close(cmd);
}'
1 path
```